# Include Category Path in Sitemap

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, event-observer, sitemaps

I want to include category path for products inside my sitemap.xml.

Currently I am using Atwix Sitemap module, to split sitemap in multiple sitemaps. See: https://github.com/Atwix/Sitemap

How can I edit this module or the default Magento code, to include full product url's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include full category path, you can create a small extension and try this:

**Event**

```
<sitemap_products_generating_before>
    <observers>
        <product_sitemap>
            <class>[module]/observer</class>
            <method>extendProductXmlSitemap</method>
       </product_sitemap>
    </observers>
</sitemap_products_generating_before>
```

**Observer**

```
public function extendProductXmlSitemap(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $items      = $collection->getItems();
    $pathes     = array();

    $categoryIds = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_category')->getCollection($observer->getStoreId());
    $categoryIds = array_keys($categoryIds);
    $categories  = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
        ->addIdFilter($categoryIds);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $productsIds = $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
        $func = function($categoryId, $productsId) {
            return sprintf('catalog/product/view/id/%d/category/%d', $productsId, $categoryId);
        };
        $pathes[] = array_map($func, array_fill(0, count($productsIds), $category->getId()), $productsIds);
    }

    $rewrites = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('target_path', array('in' => $pathes));

    foreach ($rewrites as $rewrite) {
        $item = new Varien_Object;
        $item->setId($rewrite->getIdPath());
        $item->setUrl($rewrite->getRequestPath());
        $items[$itemId] = $item;
    }

    $collection->setItems($items);
}
```